# Firebase Device token is always null and OnTokenRefresh is never called on some devices

Tags: android, firebase

I am so much frustrated, since i am continuously getting null device token on certain devices whereas its working perfectly fine on many other devices.
the phone i am talking about is running on 4.4.2.
I have added the following code into my manifiest.

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />  
<service android:name=".Services.FireBaseMsgService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".Services.FirebaseIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Please guide me on this,since i have already wasted much time on this issue searching and finding solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding `android:exported="false"` to your service !! (`FirebaseIDService`)

Comment: @SantanuSur didnt worked.

Comment: `onTokenRefresh` isnt getting called ryt ? how do you know its always null ?

Comment: yes,i am logging the value after calling FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()

Comment: where are you logging that ? `onTokenRefresh`

Comment: @SantanuSur 
IFirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() returns the token value.
i am logging the value into the console after calling the above mentioned method.

Comment: i know what it returns, i was curious about where exactly were you calling it ?

Comment: @SantanuSur its returning token on many devices and not on some.
dont know what is the issue .

Comment: actually it works on background thread !! it might be reaching the device, after you have logged it !!

Comment: It may be that on the device where token is null, check the version of google play store and update it as it contains firebase client libraries.

Comment: @ArnavRao google play services and all Gapps are already updated.

Answer (score 0):

So finally i have got the answer and this might help someone.

After searching alot - i found it was a bug in firebase 11.6.0 release which i was using - just updated it to 12.0.1 and now i am able to get the token for every device.

Answer (score 0):

The firebase device token is `null` when Firebase API is used and the device has no Google Play services installed.